# How to load the content of an old (revision) of a Wikipedia article

Tags: python, api, urllib2, wikipedia-api

I am trying to do some analysis using Python 2.7 of how the content of a Wikipedia article changes over time. I am only interested in the content of the page and found the easiest way to do this is with the [Wikipedia package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/). My code successfully loads an article and then I can use the article.content function to do my analysis.

```
import Wikipdia

# pull in wikipedia article
name = 'George W. Bush'
article = wikipedia.page(name)

object = article.content
# Do analysis here
```

The following code (I got from another Stack Exchange question) finds all the revision history that I want. From this I can extract all the revision ID's I need.

```
site = wiki.Wiki("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php")
names = ["Sherrod Brown","Maria Cantwell"]
allMembers = []
for name in labels:
     params = {'action':'query',
    'titles': name,
    'prop':'revisions',
    'rvprop':'ids|flags|timestamp|userid|user|size|comment|tags|minor',
    'rvlimit':'10'
}
req = api.APIRequest(site, params)
res = req.query(querycontinue=False)
allMembers.append(res)

# Write to a file and load it into a dictionary
with open('wiki-leg.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(allMembers, outfile, indent=2)

with open('wiki-leg.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

From here I am not sure how to get the same article.content() for a revision. I cannot seem to do it with the Wikipedia package and using urllib2 hasn't yielded easy results for text parsing. Is there a way to get the content of old versions (revisions) of a wikipedia article?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very familiar with the wikipedia library, but what you want to do seems easy with [pywikibot](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot). So you need the text from different revisions of the same page, right? Try this:

```py
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site(u"en", fam=u"wikipedia")
wpage = pywikibot.Page(site, u"Portugal")

wpHist = wpage.fullVersionHistory(total=5)
for i in wpHist:
    print i[3]
```

In each iteration you'll get information about that revision.

Comment: Note that the API has changed and now it would be `wpRevs = wpage.revisions(total=5)`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the **page content for a single revision ID**, i.e. you already have the revision ID and want just that page, not the full history, you can use `getOldVersion`:

```
import pywikibot

site = pywikibot.Site("en", "wikipedia")
page = pywikibot.Page(site, "George W. Bush")
revs = page.revisions(content=False, total = 10)
revs = list(revs)

# example
revs[9]['revid']

text = page.getOldVersion(oldid = revs[9]['revid'])
print(text)
```

Some context: getting the full history for a page with thousands of edits can take some time and for what I was trying to do I only needed a small subset of revisions. So it was quicker to query the revision history *without* content, identify the revision ID's I need, and then download the content for only those.